# CometChat requesting too many HTTP connections

Tags: .net, cloud, web-hosting, http-status-code-503

Please see picture here: 
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/RG6vn.png

I had a website i'm trying to reboot. The reason I had to shut it down was because I was hosting on winhost.com and I kept getting a 503 service error because too many connections were being requesting.

Winhost argued that: Too many http connections were being made and I needed to limit how many requests could be made from the application side of things.

CometChat Service argued that: My hosting package wasn't robust enough.

My question has multiple parts:

1) Can this be remedied by purchasing a larger hosting package that can accommodate more HTTP requests?

2) should this be something that is limited from the application side of things?

Comment: Any chat software that runs on PHP & mySQL will have to make calls to your server to check for new messages. You can reduce the number of calls but then the speed at which messages appear will be reduced. Larger hosting will definitely work and you will have to fine tune your server to accept more connections. Also check your software provider's site if they have a cloud version? I think they have a semi-hosted version as well.

Comment: could you put that in an answer so I can give you props?

Comment: I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any chat software that runs on PHP & mySQL will have to make calls to your server to check for new messages. You can reduce the number of calls but then the speed at which messages appear will be reduced. Larger hosting will definitely work and you will have to fine tune your server to accept more connections. Also check your software provider's site if they have a cloud version? I think they have a semi-hosted version as well